# Creating a copy of attribute value of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I need to create a copy/save/duplicate  of `listID` attribute of NSManagedObject `list`. The scenario is first delete list from local store and then i send request to server for deleting `list` objects using their id but when i delete objects from local store there i cannot then access object ids. Following is the code

```
List *list = (List*)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *listID = [list.listID stringValue];
[listsToDelete addObject:listID];

[context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

i tried to store object id string value in an array for later use but no avail because if at later i access `listToDelete` it is nil. Why do i need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the limited code you have shown, a few things come to mind:

1) Did you initialize your listsToDelete? I imagine that is an `NSMutableArray` type. You need to initialize it properly.

IE. `NSMutableArray* listsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

2) Have you tried logging the value of `list.listID` prior to adding it into your array? Maybe the value was `nil` to begin with?

Comment: Yup, it was a initializing problem of `NSMutableArray`. Thanks.